# Manipulating / modifying terrain data to model a new surface

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, dem

**Short question:** How to (intuitively) modify/manipulate a terrain with QGIS or alternative Open Source Software?

**The details**: In order to build a habitat (ponds and depressions) for amphibians, a terrain needs to partly be digged out to a certain depth (relative to groundwater level) and in a certain shape. I have the original terrain surface, interpolated from XYZ Data. Further I have the outlines of the ponds as a polygon shape. Now I need to modify the elevation data to represent the future suface after the ponds are built. (The overall goal is to calculate the volume of extracted material between the original surface and the new one, but that is yet another step.)

Do you know of any tools or plugins in QGIS or an other free software that allows a rather intuitive method for manipulating terrain data? I was thinking of maybe something like the "Grid editor" in Surfer, but of course I am open for anything...

Image: original surface and position of ponds/depressions
[image: original surface]

Comment: Have you tried [Serval](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Serval/) plugin already?

Comment: Thanks, Kazuhito. That one is new to me, I will give it a try :)